# Why can't you directly stub! mock objects?

Tags: mocking, rspec

I might be missing something completely obvious here, but why do I have to do this:

```
setup do
  @person = mock("person")
  @person.stub!(:name).and_return("david")
end
```

Instead of

```
@person = mock("person").stub!(:name).and_return("david")
```

What is mock("string") returning that doesn't allow it to be stubbed versus allowing @person to be stubbed?  Is mock not returning an object (perhaps just modifying some internal hash table of mock'ed out functions and then returning a separate object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `and_return` call doesn't return the stub object. `mock` does.

First, in order to have a mock object to work with, you have to create the actual mock object and assign it to a variable. When you call `mock("person").stub!...` the mock object is lost in the call chain. Your chained version would only work if `and_return` returned the original mock object.

Comment: Thanks - confused by overexposure to ARel and JQuery :)

Comment: @David - I see the problem :) Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35245/peter-lillevold) points out, @person is being assigned the value from `and_return` rather than the mock object. This turns out to be a `Proc`.

You could do this:

```
@person = mock("person").tap {|obj| obj.stub!(:name).and_return("david") }
```

Though all this is unnecessary since you can declare the stub right in the mock definition:

```
@person = mock("person", :name => "david")
```